# displaying image using canvas

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Im not able to display the image using canvas inside a loop.I have stored the image directory in the
mysql database.The image is displayed only at the final loop run

Image:

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector
z=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='*****',database='***')
a=z.cursor()

spl=Tk()
a.execute('select * from spl') #fetching the image directory from databse
splval=IntVar()
b=a.fetchall()
for j in b:
        canvas=Canvas(width=100,height=100,bg='black')
        canvas.pack()  #the image is displayed only at last loop :(
        p=PhotoImage(file=j[2])
        canvas.create_image(0,0,image=p,anchor=NW)    
        rb1=Radiobutton(spl,text=j[1],variable=splval,value=j[0],bg='#F4F570',font='Consolas 20 bold')
        rb1.pack()

Label(spl,text=' ',bg='#F4F570').pack()
b1=Button(spl,text='SUBMIT',command=vsplv,font='Consolas 20 bold')
b1.pack()

spl.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change to `canvas.p=PhotoImage(...`

Comment: you may have to assign every PhotoImage to separted variable (or keep all on list) because there is bug in `PhotoImage` which may remove image from memory - see Note on http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: Add `rb1.image = p` after `rb1.pack()` to save a reference of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANKS FOR THOSE WHO RESPONDED:)

```
    picvar=[]
    for j in b:
        picvar.append(j[1])
        lvar=len(picvar)-1
        canvas=Canvas(width=100,height=100,bg='black')
        canvas.pack()
        picvar[lvar]=PhotoImage(file=j[2])
        canvas.create_image(0,0,image=picvar[lvar],anchor=NW)
```

this one will work